# How to select multiple values from a Dictionary using Linq as simple as possible

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I need to select a number of values (into a List) from a Dictionary based on a subset of keys.

I'm trying to do this in a single line of code using Linq but what I have found so far seems quite long and clumsy. What would be the shortest (cleanest) way to do this?

This is what I have now (the keys are Strings and keysToSelect is a List of keys to select):

```
List<ValueType> selectedValues = dictionary1.Where(x => keysToSelect.Contains(x.Key))
                                            .ToDictionary<String, valueType>(x => x.Key,
                                                                             x => x.Value)
                                            .Values.ToList;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well you could start from the list instead of the dictionary:

```
var selectedValues = keysToSelect.Where(dictionary1.ContainsKey)
                     .Select(x => dictionary1[x])
                     .ToList();
```

If all the keys are guaranteed to be in the dictionary you can leave out the first `Where`:

```
var selectedValues = keysToSelect.Select(x => dictionary1[x]).ToList();
```

Note this solution is faster than iterating the dictionary, especially if the list of keys to select is small compared to the size of the dictionary, because `Dictionary.ContainsKey` is much faster than `List.Contains`.

Comment: If the keys are guaranteed to be in the dictionary, then this answer is the better one (without the Where).

Comment: Great, this is quite elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Every time I reread this 1) my head explodes, 2) I superglue the pieces back together and re-reread it, and 3) I want to upvote it again.

Comment: This is still not the most efficient option from the point of lookups as you still have to check if the key is in the dictionary twice: once to filter the keys, once to lookup the object.

This solution does not have that issue:

    var selectedValues = keysToSelect
                .Select(_ => {
                    var found = dict.TryGetValue(_, out TValue? result);
                    return (found, result);
                })
                .Where(_ => _.found)
                .Select(_ => _.result!)
                .ToList();

Answer (score 9):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, so you can simply `Select` the `Value` property:

```
 List<ValueType> selectedValues = dictionary1
           .Where(x => keysToSelect.Contains(x.Key))
           .Select(x => x.Value)
           .ToList();
```

or

```
 var selectValues = (from keyValuePair in dictionary1
                     where keysToSelect.Contains(keyValuePair.Key)
                     select keyValuePair.Value).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is not very efficient when keys are not guaranteed to exist b/c it performs two lookups.

Based on the accepted answer I came up with this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetMultiple<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEnumerable<TKey> keysToSelect)
{
    foreach (var key in keysToSelect)
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value))
            yield return value;
}
```

Not exactly a "one liner" but I find it more readable than chaining four Linq methods.

Usage:

```
var results = dictionary.GetMultiple(keysToSelect).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that all the value that you want to select are in the dictionary, you can loop through the keys instead of looping through the dictionary:

```
List<ValueType> selectedValues = keysToSelect.Select(k => dictionary1[k]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is still not the most efficient option from the point of lookups as you still have to check if the key is in the dictionary twice: once to filter the keys, once to lookup the object.

This solution does not have that issue:

```
var selectedValues = keysToSelect
  .Select(_ => {
     var found = dict.TryGetValue(_, out TValue? result);
     return (found, result);
  })
  .Where(_ => _.found)
  .Select(_ => _.result!)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I would upvote the answer, but I don't like using an underscore as a parameter name. This character has the special meaning of "discard" in C#.

Comment: This may be more efficient, but please note that I asked for "as simple as possible" / 
"the shortest (cleanest) way to do this" in terms of source code.